# Do I or don't I, have to verify the existence of the identity in a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a very simple question. Every book says that I have to verify closure and existence of the inverse. I have a book that only verifies the second, and says I can already prove that the identity exists because the inverse exists, by closure, $aa^{-1}=e \in G$. But some books say I have to verify the existence of the identity.

Which books are correct?

Comment: I'd point out you also need to verify that the subgroup is non-empty. It often happens that checking the identity is in it is the fastest way to do this. Otherwise the above proof fails because there is no actual $a$ to choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other two properties imply the existence of the identity whenever the subset is non-empty. Many authors skip the condition there is an identity by saying the following:

It is equivalent for a non-empty subset $H$ of a group $G$:

- $H$ is a subgroup of $G$
- $\forall a,b\in H$ we have $a^{-1}\in H$ and $ab\in H$

---

We also have the following for **finite** groups:

It is equivalent for a non-empty subset $H$ of a **finite** group $G$:

- $H$ is a subgroup of $G$
- $\forall a,b\in H$ we have  $ab\in H$

Comment: Is the last statement regarding ab in H the composite of a and b?

Comment: $ab$ is the product of $a$ and $b$ using the group's product.

Answer (score 0):

Your instinct is correct: if you know the subset is closed and inverses exist, then you know $aa^{-1}  = e \in H \leqslant G $. This *is* verifying that the identity is present in $H$.

Comment: Yes, but some books says that I have to verify 3 steps: closure, inverse AND identity :(

Comment: Expanding on my last sentence: once you 1. verify closure and 2. verify the existence of inverses, then you 3. verify the existence of the identity via $a\in H \implies a^{-1} \in H \implies aa^{-1} = e \in H$ where the implications appeal to 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: As closure normally refers only to "closed under multiplication", not to inverses, I guess you meant to write "inverses exist" instead of "identities exist" in the first line of your answer. But then you still miss to mention that $H$ has to be non-empty. The empty set is closed under products and taking inverse, but is *not* a subgroup.